# Code not producing correct output

Tags: php

I've tried to create a program that allows the user to input a time/duration (hh:mm). If this time/duration exceeds one hour, then 15 minutes are added to a variable called 'MaintenanceDuration'. If their input is less than or equal to an hour, 10 minutes are added.

When I run the code it only ever adds 10 minutes, despite the input being greater than an hour.

I've been told its because `$Duration` is not set/defined however surely it is when the user submits their input?

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="maintenance-formula.php" method="post">
Duration: <input type="time" name="Duration" id="Duration"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$Duration = $_POST['Duration'];

if ($Duration > strtotime('1:00:00')) {
        echo "Added 15 maintenance minutes!";
        $MaintenanceDuration = strtotime('0:15:00');
} else {
        echo "Added 10 maintenance minutes!";
        $MaintenanceDuration = strtotime('0:10:00');
}

$MaintenanceDuration = strftime('%H:%M', $MaintenanceDuration);
echo $MaintenanceDuration;

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you see when you `echo strtotime('1:00:00')`?

Comment: Produces `1476766800`

Comment: And what is `echo $_POST['Duration'];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$Duration` is strictly given in `hh:mm` format, you've gotta parse it.

```
$parsedDuration = explode(':', $Duration);

$hours = intval($parsedDuration[0]);
$mins  = intval($parsedDuration[1]);

if ($hours > 0 && $mins > 0) {
    echo "Added 15 maintenance minutes!";
    $MaintenanceDuration = strtotime('0:15:00');
} else {
    echo "Added 10 maintenance minutes!";
    $MaintenanceDuration = strtotime('0:10:00');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I tested with values both below and under one hour (1:00) and these had the correct output, however when I tested 1:00 it added 15 minutes instead of 10.